# Embedded Youtube Videos not playing when web app is added to homescreen

Tags: iphone, web-applications, youtube, homescreen

I've made an app for a client that uploads a vide to youtube and then emails them a link to a page that, when opened on Safari, displays the video and then prompts them to add the page to their homescreen as a web app.

For some reason, when the app is played in Safari the video plays fine but when it is played from homescreen it doesn't play sound through the speakers, only through the headphones. Anyone know of a reason this could be happening?

EDIT: Fixed it myself and posted to another answer
http://www.shockoe.com/blog/embedded-youtube-videos-wont-play-sound-through-speakers-when-played-from-web-apps-added-to-homescreen-fix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question! Need to use Object embed not iframe

http://www.shockoe.com/blog/embedded-youtube-videos-wont-play-sound-through-speakers-when-played-from-web-apps-added-to-homescreen-fix/